# Why doesn't this jQuery animation loop infinitely?

Tags: jquery, animation, loops

I have a jQuery animation that positively refuses to loop. It will play through the animation once and then quit.

Here it is: http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackad/fancy.html

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
function DoAgain()
{
    $('#block').stop().css('marginLeft','0px');
    var width = ($('#block').width()) / 2;
    var length = (1000 * num_ads) / document.getElementById('speed').value;
    $('#block').animate({marginLeft: '-=' + width},length,'linear',
      function() {
        DoAgain();
    });
}
```

I tried to debug the application with the Chrome JavaScript console, but according to it, everything works. (No errors, `DoAgain()` gets called fine, etc.)

I am really stuck here - a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: PS: You should make the ads stop when you mouse over one so people don't accidentally click the wrong one.

Comment: I never thought of that... thanks for sharing the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know why, but your `stop()` seems to have been breaking it. Here, I fixed it for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/34dvF/3/

```
function DoAgain()
{
    $('#block').css('marginLeft','0px');
    var width = $('#block').width() / 2;
    var length = (1000 * num_ads) / $('#speed').val();
    $('#block').animate({marginLeft: '-=' + width}, length, 'linear', DoAgain);
}
```

You don't really need the `stop()` anyway, do you? The animation has already completed before the function is called again.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Will I run into a problem then if the animation is currently in progress and I call this function?

Comment: @George: I think what will happen is this animation will be queued... so it will just go after the currently running one has finished. This functionality isn't always desirable.

Comment: It shouldn't cause harm in my case. Thanks for the help - and thanks for pointing me to jsfiddle.net - I never knew about that tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd share the solution with you all:

Apparently calling `stop()` can only be done on an animated item, so I insert the following:

```
$('table:animated').stop(true,false);
```

... and this will stop the animation only when it is running.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nT7e4/ I don't think that's the problem either. Calling `stop()` on something that isn't animated should have no effect.

Comment: @Mark: Check out the code I have on the page now - it seems to be working.